# 400 Error even if email exists in firebase

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-authentication, email-validation

I am trying user authentication with firebase in java using spring framework. When ever I try to authenticate a user using the provided emailId and password I am getting a 400 Error, but the emailId **does** exist in the fireBase authentication as well as in the firebase realtime database page. I am also able to retrieve data using uuid which is available in  fireBase authentication web page.

My code:

```
String googleAuthUrl = 
    env.getProperty("google.auth.identity.toolkit.url") +
    env.getProperty("google.auth.identity.toolkit.key"); 
Client client = Client.create();  
WebResource webResource = client.resource(googleAuthUrl);  
ClientResponse response = webResource.accept("application/json").type("application/json")
    .post(ClientResponse.class, inputJson);           
Integer responseCode = response.getStatus();  
String responseBody = response.getEntity(String.class);
logger.info("Google response : {}", responseBody);  
// ...
```

My input :
{ 
    "email": "abc@gmail.com",
    "password":"test123"
}

Exception encountered:

```
Google response : {
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "EMAIL_NOT_FOUND",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "EMAIL_NOT_FOUND",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "invalid"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Can anyone explain the reason for this exception and how to overcome the problem ! Instead of making a REST call is there an SDK available for user authentication ?

Comment: See the [Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users) for user management.

Comment: I have already seen it. There ia no sdk available for authentication of user. Can you say something about the exception i encountered?

Answer (score 1):

I just had a similar problem with same library but in flutter.

The problem was that I was sending the email with a white space at the end...

So, I don't know if you solved it but a `trim()` function can solved it, if is the case sure